# .vcxproj in source control

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have been reading lots of questions regarding whether vcxproj files should be added to source control or not. The consensus seems to be that they should, but when opening the files I noticed that there are a lot of user specific paths contained within.

Seeing as this is a project that is being worked on by a number of people, should I still add it to source control? It seems like it would clash with other peoples' setups.

Comment: You should use property files, which can be included in the project file, to keep user-specific paths easy to change and exclude. Pulling all the paths out into a property file can be tedious at first, but is well worth it (single source of truth for paths, all projects can import them, and users can change their paths without worrying about others overwriting them).

Comment: Project files (vcproj(x) should not contain absolute path (user specific) in the settings (*); When specifying paths use predefined "macros" (for example $(IntDir) ) or relative paths (but they will be relative to exiting macros (for example $(SolutionDir))
(*) Yes there are exceptions to the rules, for example for global external includes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Of course they need to be added to source control, *.vcxproj **is*** the project file. Quoting [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/build-system-changes):

> Project files no longer use the *.vcproj* file name extension. Visual
>   Studio automatically converts project files that were created by an
>   earlier release of Visual C++ to the format that is used by the
>   current system. For more information about how to manually upgrade a
>   project, see */Upgrade* (*devenv.exe*).
>
> In the current release, the file name extension for a project file is
>   *.vcxproj*.

The *.vcxproj.user* files, on the other hand, do not need to be added to source control. The link above describes what each of these files contain as well.

Comment: This is true, however the _.vcxproj_ file contains lots of data that seems specific to me for example:  `<Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\pass\build\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp</Outputs>`

Comment: @user524351 Are you sure you haven't added that path to the project options explicitly? I don't see any paths in my vcxproj files.

Comment: I didn't but these files were automatically generated by CMake. Perhaps CMake added them. Not sure why it would though.

Comment: @user524351 CMake-generated project files should be treated like build output files. They should not be checked in to source control, or even moved from their original folders. If you move your source code to a new folder or machine, you must re-run CMake to generate new project files.

Answer (score 7):

It is the project file for your project.  So yes, you'd better check that in.  The only file that you might not want to check-in is the .vcxproj.user file.  It contains user-specific overrides, particularly debugger settings.

You could only make such a mistake if you are not operating Explorer in "programmer" mode.  It has the nasty habit of hiding filename extensions.  Fix that with Control Panel + Folder Options, View tab, untick the "Hide extensions for known file types" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to pull [OPs comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015265/vcxproj-in-source-control#comment17667773_13015434) into an answer for future visitors.

> I didn't [add absolute paths] but these files were automatically generated by CMake. Perhaps CMake added them. Not sure why it would though.

If you’re using CMake, then vcxproj files are considered build artifacts and should NOT be committed into version control.

If you are using Visual Studio as your build system, and not using CMake to generate vcxproj files, then you SHOULD commit the vcxproj file.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful way of handling paths is via environment variables. You can evaluate variables like $(PythonDir) to control paths without putting them in vcxproj file. This works if you use cmake or vcxproj files directly.