# Using boost with VS project on Git

Tags: git, boost, visual-studio-2012

I could hardly type any good request to google to find an answer. I have a project with Visual Studio (2012) and this project is versioned on git (this file is versioned * : **vcxproj**). I'd like to use Boost library in the project, so I have to set the location for it, but this manner will change the **vcxproj**, so the other guy will have to change it for his pc and so on. How to solve such problem without removing this file from versioning?

*I have read here: [.vcxproj in source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015265/vcxproj-in-source-control) that the file should be versiond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs frequently in version control scenarios: Parts of a file depend on the local environment, these parts should not be under version control. There are two principal ways to deal with this:

- Postulate a consistent local environment
- Put only those parts of the file under version control which are valid independent of the local environment. Create a script that adds the parts that depend on the local environment  to an *unversioned* copy of that file.

I see three solutions to this particular problem:

1. Agree on a common location for installing Boost. By that, "the other guy" won't have to modify his copy of the `.vcxproj` file.
2. Refer to Boost using a symbolic link from within your Visual Studio solution. Same logic as 1.
3. Create a script that copies the `.vcxproj` file and adds the reference to Boost to that copy. Refer to the copied `.vcxproj` file from your `.sln` file, but **do not** add it to Git -- add it to `.gitignore`. This is the most generic way for dealing with problems of this kind, but it is also difficult to handle in practice -- actually committing modifications to the `.vcxproj` file now requires extra work.

Answer (score 0):

For boost I add it directly to my global include/libraries path. For this approach, go to the property manager window, then expand any C++ project and select Microsoft.Cpp.XXX.user and select properties. This will give you a project property sheet that applies to all projects for that platform on your account. Within this sheet you modify the VC++ Directories tab to add the appropriate paths.

For less "global" libraries, I designate a known directory to hold property sheets that contain additional compiler settings for using a specific library. These will hold the include and library paths, but can also have additional settings like defines and linker inputs. I personally use 'C:\SDKs' as the designated directory. So I might have something like 'C:\SDKs\DirectX11-x86.props'. This approach minimizes what needs to be hard-coded, and allows for more options than just include/library paths. One caveat: you must ensure the path is absolute, where visual studio likes to make them relative.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to include boost in your code tree, such that there is no external dependency on boost being installed on the machine, which would also reduce the requirements for setting up the development machine.

Since boost is open source and available on GitHub (https://github.com/boostorg), you should be able to map it in using [git submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Another option is to use the [boost Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost/)